# Gradle SonarRunner: fail build on failed Quality Gate

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, teamcity, sonar-runner

I am executing Gradle SonarRunner task on my Android code as a part of Team City build.

It fails Quality Gate on SonarQube, but console build is successful and there is no info about failed QG in logs:

```
[10:57:35][Step 1/3] 10:57:36.323 INFO  - Loaded quality gate 'Android'
[10:57:36][Step 1/3] 10:57:36.397 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-12-07)
[10:57:36][Step 1/3] 10:57:36.405 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-11-08, analysis of Thu Nov 26 13:27:50 CET 2015)
[10:57:36][Step 1/3] 10:57:36.411 INFO  - Compare to previous version (2015-12-07)
[10:57:36][Step 1/3] 10:57:36.642 INFO  - Execute decorators...
[10:58:19][Step 1/3] 10:58:20.189 INFO  - Store results in database
[10:58:59][Step 1/3] 10:59:00.330 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 2698ms, dir size=4 MB
[10:59:09][Step 1/3] 10:59:09.888 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 9558ms, zip size=3 MB
[10:59:09][Step 1/3] 10:59:10.245 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 357ms
[10:59:09][Step 1/3] 10:59:10.245 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse [###############]
[10:59:09][Step 1/3] 10:59:10.245 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] Total time: 6:05.725s
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] Final Memory: 44M/1294M
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] 
[10:59:10][Step 1/3] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I'd like to recognize such event by failing Gradle task or at least checking logs for some specific failure message (eg. "ANALYSIS FAILED"). How can I achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention your SonarQube Server version. Breaking the build is not available in the current server version, 5.2, but was there in v5.1 and before with [the Build Breaker Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin), and native support [should return soon](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-123).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! We are using 5.1.2, so I'll try with the plugin.

Comment: Ok, the plugin helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After Sonarqube 7.7 the build breaker does not seem to work anymore.

Since 1.3.0, this Android Gradle plugin has build breaker capabilities, you might want to check it out: https://github.com/pinchbv/android-analyzer